# Regex modification php

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex: `/\*([^<|\n|\r]+)/`

which matches all characters in a string starting with a * and ending in a new line or a '<', how can I modify this regex to not match strings if they start with a ** (so it will not match if the second character is also a *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
/(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)([^<\n\r]+)/
```

Also, `[^<|\n|\r]` doesn't do what you think it does. It will match anything that isn't `<`, `\n`, `\r`, or a literal `|` character. You don't need the `|` inside a character class unless you want to match a literal `|`.

Comment: This is matching `**texttexttextext` - it should not

Comment: This still seems to match `**123<`

Comment: @Cart - `|` does mean or, but only outside of a character class. Inside the `[]`, the or is implied. If you wanted to do something like `(a|b|c)` (a or b or c), you would need the `|`.

Comment: @James C and @Cart - I made the mistake of using a lookbehind without a lookahead; now I see you need both. Try it now, it should work.

Comment: @Cart - Glad that helped! Here's some more info on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[abc]`) vs. [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (`a|b|c`).

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. It's called a "zero-width negative look-ahead assertion"

```
/\*(?!\*)([^<|\n|\r]+)/
```

Comment: This is matching `**texttexttextex ` starting from the second *, I want it to not match at all if it contains two *'s at the start of the string

Comment: You actually need both the lookbehind and the lookahead. If the pattern started off with a `^`, the lookahead would be enough; but without the anchor you need both. Likewise, the fact that `[^<\n\r]` could match another `*` means that the lookbehind isn't enough either. This tripped me up as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
/\*[^\*]([^<|\n|\r]+)/
```

The alteration effectively says "match a * but only when the next character is not a *"

Comment: hmm, this matches the the string starting from the second *, I do not want it to match at all. `**texttexttextext` matches `*texttexttextext` but it shouldn't. It should only match if the beginning has only one *

Comment: This will require at least two characters following the `\*`, instead of one; more importantly, it will not block `**blah`, merely cause matching to start after the first `*`. So from `**blah` you would get `*b(lah)` as a match. Also, `*x<` would fail entirely instead of matching `*x`.

Comment: Cart, it seems like the regex youve posted above is different from mine, you're missing some brackets in there. Agreed with the latter comments though, lookarounds are the way forward.